# Help(Clash Of Clans)

Tags: game-center

I've been playing clash of clans on my iPod on my own Game Center account. My younger brother and I also shared the same Apple id, so we would get eachothers 
games that we downloaded. Now my younger brother wants the play clash of clans on his iPod, so I made a brand new Apple id for his iPod and made sure nothing from mine (Apple id) was on his. But everytime he loads clash of clans, it's still on my account. Im really confused and woul love if anyone can help me out or has the same problem. Thank you:)

Comment: Which Apple ID is being used to sign into Gamecenter?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. On the iDevice that hasn’t played CoC before (I will call it #1), create a new Apple ID.
2. Download CoC on it and finish the tutorial.
3. On the other iDevice, go to the Settings and sign out your current Game Center account.
4. Sign back in with the new account which you’ve created on the #1.
   You’ve done.

Source: http://cocland.com/tricks-and-tips/play-multiple-clash-clans-accounts

Answer (score 0):

Check the AppleID logged into Game Center on your brother's iPod & try re-installing Clash of Clans, just in case.